# Duplicate title tags Magento issue?

Tags: seo, magento-1.7

I have a magento based website. For seo reasons I am getting Duplicate Title Tags problem from google.

For example **12" Marakesh**:

1. */12-marakesh.html*
2. */memory-foam-mattresses/12-marakesh.html*
3. */memory-foam-mattresses/enso-sleep-systems/12-marakesh.html*

For one product I get these 3 pages. But I only need one.

How do I make a product list only once not thrice ?

I read [this tutorial](http://www.rockymountainsearchacademy.com/2012/02/10/seo-basic-tip-010/), but it won't help much coz there are quite a few pages that needs adjustments.

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: the following module will resolve your problem for sure-: http://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-extensions/magento-seo-catalog-urls.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Admin menu, **System -> Configuration**,

on the left side, choose **Catalog** (under Catalog tab).

On **Search Engine Optimizations**, set **Use Categories Path for Product URLs** to No